# Number phone validation in java

Tags: java, validation, mobile, numbers

How to validate an Algerian phone number using java? Such as `0775896012` and have prefix `07` or `05` or `06`

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance(); 
PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse("phone_number", "");  
phoneUtil.isValidNumber(numberProto) == true ? "valid" : "phone no not valid"
```

Comment: What are the rules? Just check if it has one of those prefixes?

Comment: yes, and it must be contain 10 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to validate the phone number:

```
numberProto.matches("^0(?:7|5|6)\\d{8}$")
```

This would check the length and prefix of provided string.

Test: https://regex101.com/r/GKZHb1/1

More info on regex: http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/#section-12